# Как дубень данные от промиса ждал

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Небольшой JavaScript, запускаемый через Node JS:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

class Client {
    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
        this.onLoad = true;
    }

    PushResult(NewData) {
        this.data = NewData;
        this.onLoad = false;
    }

    GetData() {
        return fetch('http://my-first-api/gate/get')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.PushResult(data))
    }
}

let client = new Client();

client.GetData();

console.log(client);
```

В итоге экземпляр класса имеет такие свойства:

```
Client { data: [], onLoad: true }
```

Т.е. ни свойство `data` не заполнилось, ни флаг onLoad не обновился, хотя если внутри функции PushResult прописать `console.log(NewData)` то видно, что сервис вернул данные.
Кучу примеров посмотрел, везде в callback-функции `then` суют `console.log()`, а как реально обрабатывать полученные данные, если вызов функции, изменяющей свойство объекта не срабатывает? Или я что-то недопонимаю в работе ООП / Promise'ов?

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно. Так происходит потому что Вы ждете выполнение функции, но не говорите внешне что она асинхронная и её надо подождать. Попробуйте так (для удобства избавимся от then в функции):

```
async GetData() {
    let response = await fetch('http://my-first-api/gate/get')
    const data = await response.json();
    return this.PushResult(data)
}

client.GetData().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Либо используйте старый синтаксис, но тогда необходимо вернуть `promise`:

```
GetData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch('http://my-first-api/gate/get')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                 const result = this.PushResult(data)
                 resolve(result);
             })
    })
}
client.GetData().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```